Special Case of Minimum Cost Flow Problem with Variable Cost
I am working on an optimization problem similar to MCF with variable cost, but with an adjustment in the objective function. The cost function $f$ to minimize that is continuous, piece-wise linear and strictly increasing with given lower and upper bounds (think of $x^3$ defined on a closet interval). However, $f$ is concave below $0$ and convex above $0$ (this means that the cost can take negative values as well, acting as reward or profit).
Had $f$ been convex everywhere, I could transform this problem to an equivalent LP one and solve it by using the linear segments of the PWL as inequality constraints.
I would like to do the same in my case but I am struggling to figure out the correct way. (The alternative is to model it as a MIP problem which I do not want to).

The problem is nonconvex, so any linearization will require integer variables.

@RobPratt Would it make sense to introduce a binary variable to split the constraint for $x < 0$ and $x > 0$?

That will not be enough because you still would have nonconvexity for the $x<0$ portion.

@RobPratt So, there is no way to handle this other than using binary variables for each linear segment of the PWL cost function?

There are other linearizations of nonconvex PWL functions, but they all require binary variables.

Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4945180/converting-x3-optimization-to-an-equivalent-lp-problem

Could you mention some of them, or maybe provide some reference, papers to look up?

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167637713001211

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1155/2013/101376

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
